# How to use CAST as SIGNED in Stored Procedure to solve BIGINT - MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm new to stored procedure when I query without stored procedure it's working fine, but when I run the stored procedure it shows error.

> **ERROR 1690 (22003): BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range**

```
DELIMITER ;;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_price;
Create Procedure sp_price(
 IN user_date INT,
 OUT exp INT,

BEGIN

select case 
          when (cast((((start_date) + (31536000 * a))-t2.start_time) as unsigned) )>0  
             then sum(t2.price) 
          else 0 
       end 
into exp 
from product t1 
join customer t2 on t1.p_id=t2.c_id 
where t2.created >= user_date; 

END

;;
```

Comment: You say you use mysql, than why did you tag sql server? I've removed sql server tag, please don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Thanks @HoneyBadger, mistakenly i was tagged sql server. sorry!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to declare the variable exp as unsigned

Example:

```
 ....
   Create Procedure sp_price(
   IN user_date INT,
   OUT exp INT unsigned
 ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally worked!!! Here's Solved one...

```
select case 
          when (((start_date) + (31536000 * a))- (cast(t2.start_time) as signed))>0  
             then sum(t2.price) 
          else 0 
       end 
into exp 
from product t1 
join customer t2 on t1.p_id=t2.c_id 
where t2.created >= user_date;
```